# Putting strings or enums into LMDB

Tags: serialization, rust, traits, lmdb

I want to write some data to my database using [the lmdb crate](https://github.com/danburkert/lmdb-rs). I am writing an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A { astr: String, bstr: String },
    B { i: u32 },
    C,
}
```

The `put` function of an `lmdb::RwTransaction` has following definition:

```
fn put<K, D>(
    &mut self,
    database: Database,
    key: &K,
    data: &D,
    flags: WriteFlags,
) -> Result<()>
where
    K: AsRef<[u8]>,
    D: AsRef<[u8]>,
```

How do I put `MyEnum::A` into the database, since it does not implement `AsRef<[u8]>`?

I could just convert the data to JSON and write that JSON into the database, but this costs performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use *some* serialization format because you cannot directly put the bits that represent `MyEnum` in memory into the database (because the internal implementations of enums and `String` may not be stable across Rust versions, and `String` at least uses pointers internally).

You do not have to use JSON specifically.  (JSON is indeed quite inefficient.)  You could pick something else supported by [serde](https://serde.rs/) (which appears to be the de-facto type-directed serialization library for Rust).